# how do you prove you are not a bot with a zero knowledge proof?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I communicate with another person online,

I know he is a person because sometimes he also writes real messages

but at random timeframes whenever I send him a message he only responds with a dot

maybe the other person is playing a game with me but maybe he leaves his desk and turns on a bot

is there a zero knowledge proof such that the other person shows that he is not a bot without doing something a bot wouldnt do?

A bot only sends dots

Therefore a person would not send dots

The person/bot also only replies after I sent him a message with one dot, so he cannot send several dots at once

The communication looks like that:

A: normal text

B: normal text

A: normal text

B: normal text

...(after random time)

A:normal text

B: .

A:normal text

B: .

A:normal text

B: .

...(after random time)

A: normal text

B: normal text

.....

B wants to show that he wrote the dots manually in the exchange without revealing his secret information (whether or not he really sat behind the computer and wrote the dots manually and not using a bot)

Comment: "but at random timeframes whenever I send him a message he only responds with a dot; maybe the other person is playing a game with me "; or possibly he is using a dot to mean a specific message, perhaps "I agree with what you said" or "I received your message; I don't have time to reply" or maybe "Stop bothering me".  Perhaps you should ask him?

Comment: @poncho no you can assume the dots have no meaning, he is either actively playing a game with me (because the messages are sent on a messageboard and for every message you send you get a point, and the more points you have the more respect you get (no matter if they make senser)) or he uses a bot to do the dirty work for him

Comment: Oh, so this is not something you encountered in real life - this is a thought expirement...

Comment: @poncho this really happens to me and its a problem that occured to me here is the conversation with me (highinhibition) and arescel  https://ibb.co/TrkT31M

Comment: Is this dots/no dots really part of the problem? Because from what you have written, the fact that the entity sends a dot means that it must be a bot. Right?

Comment: Also, since you sent a message of just a dot, you are a bot.

Comment: @bmm6o a person (arescel) could also send dots to pretend/to simulate a bot. he claims later he really wrote these dots manually and he is ready to show me this with a zkp, i.e. he wants to show me that he can write something else except "one single dot after every reply from me" without revealing that he can write something else now I have to design a zkp with commitment,challenge,response but i wonder how

Comment: None of your sentences end with a dot. I don't know if this is a joke or not, but I guess they are just trying to get your attention on that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I will edit the question to make clear what I mean